# Ionic 5 Capacitor 3 App not showing up on Android 8 but run app from android studio works well

Tags: android, angular, gradle, ionic-framework, capacitor

I've got an ionic 5.36.0 app with capacitor 3.1.2, angular 12.0.1
my sdk's are:

```
varables.gradle:

ext {
   minSdkVersion = 21
   compileSdkVersion = 30
   targetSdkVersion = 30
   androidxActivityVersion = '1.2.0'
   androidxAppCompatVersion = '1.2.0'
   androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion = '1.1.0'
   androidxCoreVersion = '1.3.2'
   androidxFragmentVersion = '1.3.0'
   junitVersion = '4.13.1'
   androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.2'
   androidxEspressoCoreVersion = '3.3.0'
   cordovaAndroidVersion = '7.0.0'
}
```

My problem is now, when i install the app from play store on an Android 10 device, everything works fine. When i install the app on an android 8 device, its installing right but i can't find or start the app on my device.
If i'm doing **"run on device"** from Android Studio with the same Android 8 phone the complete **app is working well**, without any problems. Do you have any ideas?

this is the app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rkm.neimosapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, i figured out that there was an error in my AndroidManifest.xml.

This is how it was:

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="@string/custom_url_scheme" />
  </intent-filter>
```

This is how it it has to be:

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
```